# I can't find a legit reason on why this Matlab code takes a long time to compute, or it might not give out a result?

Tags: matlab

I have this piece of code that works with integral on Matlab:

```
xmin = -8;
ymin = -8;
xmax = 8;
ymax = 8;

syms x y;
f2 =18-3/sqrt(x^2+ y^2)+sin(sqrt(x^2+y^2))+(sqrt(200-(x^2+y^2)+10\sin(x)+10\sin(y)))/1000;
sym_area2 = eval(int(int(f2,y,ymin,ymax),x,xmin,xmax));

double(sym_area2)
```

When it is trying to calculate the `double(sym_area2)` Matlab will just stuck and won't give out a result for a long time. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: This seems weird. Going from a symbolic to a numeric value might take some time, but shouldn't be very long. Is it truly that line wich hangs and is it reproducible with other integrals?

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, i'm pretty sure, since i do get a result of `sym_area2`

Comment: Reproduced on 17b, curiously it even seems to take an age to `disp(sym_area2)`...